# Filter out certain XML nodes and form another XML with these nodes and their ancestors and child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xslt-3.0

I have below XML data and I need to filter certain XML nodes and form another XML data with those nodes and it's ancestor nodes as well as all of it's child nodes. I am new to XSLT and tried different approach using XSLT but nothing is working.

Can this be achieved in XSLT or not?

Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>`enter code here`
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000017</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>WEEKACTIVE</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>StayActive</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000064</periodId>
         <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>GAME</awardType>
            <awardCode>GCH009</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>REWARD</awardType>
            <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000065</periodId>
         <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>REWARD</awardType>
            <awardCode>EHNC002</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000066</periodId>
         <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>REWARD</awardType>
            <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000067</periodId>
         <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>GAME</awardType>
            <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
</MessageDetails>
```

Search Criteria #1: awardType = GAME

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000017</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>WEEKACTIVE</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>StayActive</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000064</periodId>
         <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>GAME</awardType>
            <awardCode>GCH009</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000067</periodId>
         <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>GAME</awardType>
            <awardCode>GCH008</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
</MessageDetails>
```

Search Criteria #2: awardType = GAME and periodStatus = COMPLETED and challengeCode = QUITSUGAR

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000067</periodId>
         <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>GAME</awardType>
            <awardCode>GCH008</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
</MessageDetails>
```

Search Criteria #3: challengeCode = WEEKACTIVE & periodId = 1000000064

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <MessageDetails>
       <challengeDetails>
          <challengeId>1000000017</challengeId>
          <challengeCode>WEEKACTIVE</challengeCode>
          <challengeCategory>StayActive</challengeCategory>
          <challengePeriodsDetails>
             <periodId>1000000064</periodId>
             <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
             <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
             <challengeAwardIssued>
                <awardType>GAME</awardType>
                <awardCode>GCH009</awardCode>
             </challengeAwardIssued>
          </challengePeriodsDetails>
       </challengeDetails>
    </MessageDetails>
```

Search Criteria #4: periodId = 1000000066

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>
   <challengeDetails>
      <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
      <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
      <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
      <challengePeriodsDetails>
         <periodId>1000000066</periodId>
         <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
         <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
         <challengeAwardIssued>
            <awardType>REWARD</awardType>
            <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
         </challengeAwardIssued>
      </challengePeriodsDetails>
   </challengeDetails>
</MessageDetails>
```

Search Criteria #5: awardType = 'GAME' and awardCode= 'EHNC001'

Required output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>`enter code here`
       <challengeDetails>
          <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
          <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
          <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
          <challengePeriodsDetails>
             <periodId>1000000067</periodId>
             <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
             <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
             <challengeAwardIssued>
                <awardType>GAME</awardType>
                <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
             </challengeAwardIssued>
          </challengePeriodsDetails>
       </challengeDetails>
    </MessageDetails>
```

Output received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MessageDetails>`enter code here`
       <challengeDetails>
          <challengeId>1000000017</challengeId>
          <challengeCode>WEEKACTIVE</challengeCode>
          <challengeCategory>StayActive</challengeCategory>
          <challengePeriodsDetails>
             <periodId>1000000064</periodId>
             <periodNumber>2</periodNumber>
             <periodStatus>INPROGRESS</periodStatus>
          </challengePeriodsDetails>
       </challengeDetails>
       <challengeDetails>
          <challengeId>1000000018</challengeId>
          <challengeCode>QUITSUGAR</challengeCode>
          <challengeCategory>QuitSugar</challengeCategory>
          <challengePeriodsDetails>
             <periodId>1000000067</periodId>
             <periodNumber>3</periodNumber>
             <periodStatus>COMPLETED</periodStatus>
             <challengeAwardIssued>
                <awardType>GAME</awardType>
                <awardCode>EHNC001</awardCode>
             </challengeAwardIssued>
          </challengePeriodsDetails>
       </challengeDetails>
    </MessageDetails>
```

XSLT used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[not(challengePeriodsDetails/challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME' and challengePeriodsDetails/challengeAwardIssued/awardCode= 'EHNC001')]" />

<xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[not(challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME' and challengeAwardIssued/awardCode= 'EHNC001')]" />

<xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails/challengeAwardIssued[not(awardType = 'GAME' and awardCode= 'EHNC001')]" />

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would approach with XML and XPath in your program code.  Read each criteria XML, and mark the matching elements in the original XML.  Then remove all elements without a match, and save the XML as a copy.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamWalseth for the reply. Let me check on this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to filter out `challengeDetails` and `challengePeriodsDetails` given some predicates. To filter out elements in XSL, you just have to provide empty templates matching the elements you don't want.

### Query 1

This is a nice and simple query for starting. Just start from the copy-all template `node()|@*`, and add two rules to filter out what's not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[
      not(challengePeriodsDetails/challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME')
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[
      not(challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME')
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Query 2

The crux here is to filter out the `challengePeriodsDetails` not satisfying both of the predicates. We work on these elements, **not** on `challengeDetails`, which is why the predicate contains another predicate. Without it we would filter out too much data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[
      not(challengePeriodsDetails[
        challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME' and periodStatus = 'COMPLETED'
      ])
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[
      not(challengeAwardIssued/awardType = 'GAME' and periodStatus = 'COMPLETED')
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Query 3

The particularity here is that we do not need to worry about challengeCode in the template about `challengePeriodsDetails`, since its parent would not appear in the final document anyway.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[
      not(challengeCode = 'WEEKACTIVE' and challengePeriodsDetails/periodId = '1000000064')
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[
      not(periodId = '1000000064')
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Query 4

This one looks like query 1, I can only recommend that you try to do it yourself before looking at the code to prove yourself you have improved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[not(challengePeriodsDetails/periodId = '1000000066')]" />

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[not(periodId = '1000000066')]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Query 5

You were so close! The trick is to test `awardType` and `awardCode` for the same `challengeAwardIssued`. You have to use a test on this node. Here is a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails[
      not(challengePeriodsDetails/challengeAwardIssued[
        awardType = 'GAME' and awardCode = 'EHNC001'
      ])
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="/MessageDetails/challengeDetails/challengePeriodsDetails[
      not(challengeAwardIssued[
        awardType = 'GAME' and awardCode = 'EHNC001'
      ])
    ]" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Fabian . Its working. Could you please help to figure out the scenario #5 added above. With the XSLT I am using it seems like for challengeDetails and challengePeriodDetails nodes, awardType = 'GAME' and awardCode= 'EHNC001' is being matched from multiple challengAwardIssued nodes and hence first challengeDetails and challengePeriodDetails block is coming in output.

Comment: Almost! I updated my answer accordingly :-)

Comment: You're very welcome! Please accept the answer using the mark, so that other members of the site know they should not focus anymore on this question :-)